# How to construct a dodecahedron and texture its sides

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, polygons

I want to create a 3-dimensional model of a planet based on a dodecahedron and give each side a different texture representing the dominant landscape and other content of that area. (Alternatively a globe seperated into 12 pentagons would be even better, but is probably even more complex.)

As this a game project I would like to do it in Unity3d, but any approach (scripted or in a free 3d graphics tool) would be helpful.

I already looked into the geometry of platonic bodies and tried to figure out how to draw pentagons and then just angle them appropriately, or just get a ready solution for this, but so far I have not found any approach.

Comment: It sounds like you want a 3D modelling program rather than a 3D game engine. Take a look at Blender (free) and this question about [creating a dodecahedron](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-generate-a-dodecahedron).

Comment: The platonic body plug-in seems to not exist any more and the Bevel-solution was simply beyond my meager Blender-skills.. But your answer pointed me in the right direction...

Answer (score 2):

After some more fiddling around, I did find an answer:

**Step 1: Create a Pentagon in Blender**

This is actually extremely simple. Create a circle and reduce the number of vertices to 5. I actually went with a cylinder with dimensions X=1, Y=1, Z=0.1, but the overall solution is the same for a flat pentagon.

**Step 2: Get it into Unity3d**

Unity3d imports .blend files naturally, so I just saved the pentagon as .blend file and imported it as Asset in Unity3d.

**Step 3: Put the Pentagon on a stick.**

To easily rotate the pentagon around the center of the later dodecahedron, I created a Cylinder in Unity3d with dimensions X=0.1, Y=2, Z=0.1. Then I put the Pentagon - as a child object - at the exact end (Transform Y=9,75 for my 3d-pentagon, 10 if using flat pentagon and Rotate X=90) of that cylinder. I did the same for the opposite end, with the pentagon turned around. (Transform =-9,75 and Rotate X=90, Z=180) to do both halfs at the same time.

**Step 3: Play around with Rotation and Scaling**

So now I can duplicate and rotate the Cylinder (with attached Pentagon) by X=63.435 (angle between the sides of a Dodecahedron) and Y=180 (so edges face each other) to get it into the right position. Now I have to find the right scaling of the Pentagons to close the gap which happens to be reasonably close at 15.275. Repeat five times with the respective angles (y=180 +/- multiples of 72, the angle between sides of a pentagon).

**Done.**

Answer (score 1):

First create some Math helpers:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public static class MathUtils
{

    public static Vector3 MultiplyMatrixAndVector(float[,] m, Vector3 v) 
    {
        return new Vector3(
            v.x * m[0, 0] + v.y * m[0, 1] + v.z * m[0, 2],
            v.x * m[1, 0] + v.y * m[1, 1] + v.z * m[1, 2],
            v.x * m[2, 0] + v.y * m[2, 1] + v.z * m[2, 2]
        );
    }

    public static Vector3 RotateVectorAroundAxis(Vector3 vector, Vector3 a, Vector3 b, double angle)
    {
        var normalizedAxis = (b - a).normalized;
        var x = normalizedAxis.x;
        var y = normalizedAxis.y;
        var z = normalizedAxis.z;
        var translationVector = ProjectPointOnAxis(vector, a, b);
        var c = (float) Math.Cos(angle);
        var s = (float) Math.Sin(angle);
        var rotationMatrix = new float[3, 3];

        rotationMatrix[0, 0] = c + x * x * (1 - c);
        rotationMatrix[0, 1] = x * y * (1 - c) - z * s;
        rotationMatrix[0, 2] = x * z * (1 - c) + y * s;
        rotationMatrix[1, 0] = y * x * (1 - c) + z * s;
        rotationMatrix[1, 1] = c + y * y * (1 - c);
        rotationMatrix[1, 2] = y * z * (1 - c) - x * s;
        rotationMatrix[2, 0] = z * x * (1 - c) - y * s;
        rotationMatrix[2, 1] = z * y * (1 - c) + x * s;
        rotationMatrix[2, 2] = c + z * z * (1 - c);

        return MultiplyMatrixAndVector(rotationMatrix, vector - translationVector) + translationVector;
    }

    public static Vector3 ProjectPointOnAxis(Vector3 vector, Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
    {
        var ba = b - a;
        var lambda = Vector3.Dot(ba, vector - a) / Vector3.Dot(ba, ba);

        return a + lambda * ba;
    }

}
```

Then create a polyhedron manager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class PolyhedronManager
{
    public static GameObject CreatePolyhedron(string name)
    {
        var material = Resources.Load("Materials/Cube") as Material;
        var gameObject = new GameObject();

        Mesh mesh;

        switch (name)
        {
            case "hexahedron":
            {
                mesh = CreatePolyhedronMesh(4, Math.PI / 2);
                break;
            }

            case "tetrahedron":
            {
                mesh = CreatePolyhedronMesh(3, Math.Acos(1d / 3));
                break;
            }

            case "octahedron":
            {
                mesh = CreatePolyhedronMesh(3, Math.Acos(-1d / 3));
                break;
            }

            case "icosahedron":
            {
                mesh = CreatePolyhedronMesh(3, Math.Acos(-Math.Sqrt(5) / 3));
                break;
            }

            case "dodecahedron":
            {
                mesh = CreatePolyhedronMesh(5, 2 * Math.Atan2(1 + Math.Sqrt(5), 2));
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid polyhedron name");
            }
        }

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = material;
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        gameObject.name = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0);

        return gameObject;
    }

    private static List<Vector3> CreatePolygonVertices(int nSides, Vector3 origin, Vector3 normal, Vector3 firstNode, bool shouldUseFirstNode)
    {
        var angle = 2 * Math.PI / nSides;
        var distanceFromCenter = (float) Math.Sqrt(0.5 / (1 - Math.Cos(angle)));
        var actualFirstNode = shouldUseFirstNode ? firstNode : origin + distanceFromCenter * Vector3.right;

        var vertices = new List<Vector3> {actualFirstNode};

        for (var i = 1; i < nSides; i++)
        {
            vertices.Add(MathUtils.RotateVectorAroundAxis(vertices[i - 1], origin, origin + normal, angle));
        }

        return vertices;
    }

    private static Mesh CreatePolyhedronMesh(int nSides, double dihedralAngle)
    {
        var supplementaryAngle = Math.PI - dihedralAngle;
        var origin = Vector3.zero;
        var faces = new List<List<Vector3>> {CreatePolygonVertices(nSides, origin, Vector3.up, origin, false)};
        var centers = new List<Vector3> {origin};

        var facesQueue = new List<List<Vector3>> {faces[0]};
        var centersQueue = new List<Vector3> {centers[0]};

        while (true)
        {
            if (facesQueue.Count == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            var face = facesQueue[0];
            var center = centersQueue[0];

            facesQueue.RemoveAt(0);
            centersQueue.RemoveAt(0);

            for (var i = 0; i < nSides; i++)
            {
                var a = face[i];
                var b = face[i == nSides - 1 ? 0 : i + 1];
                var dihedralAxis = b - a;
                var pivot = (b + a) / 2;
                var p = pivot - center;
                var nextCenter = pivot + p;
                var rotatedCenter = MathUtils.RotateVectorAroundAxis(nextCenter, a, b, supplementaryAngle);

                var centerAlreadyExists = false;

                centers.ForEach(existingCenter =>
                {    
                    if ((rotatedCenter - existingCenter).sqrMagnitude < 0.01)
                    {
                        centerAlreadyExists = true;
                    }
                });

                if (centerAlreadyExists)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var normal = Vector3.Cross(p, dihedralAxis);
                var nextFace = CreatePolygonVertices(nSides, nextCenter, normal, a, true)
                    .ConvertAll(new Converter<Vector3, Vector3>(vertex => MathUtils.RotateVectorAroundAxis(vertex, a, b, supplementaryAngle)));

                faces.Add(nextFace);
                centers.Add(rotatedCenter);

                facesQueue.Add(nextFace);
                centersQueue.Add(rotatedCenter);
            }
        }

        var vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        var triangles = new List<int>();
        var c = -1;

        for (var i = 0; i < faces.Count; i++)
        {
            var face = faces[i];
            var center = centers[i];

            c++;
            vertices.Add(center);

            var centerVertexIndex = c;

            for (var j = 0; j < face.Count; j++)
            {
                var vertex = face[j];

                c++;
                vertices.Add(vertex);
                triangles.Add(centerVertexIndex);
                triangles.Add(c);
                triangles.Add(j == face.Count - 1 ? centerVertexIndex + 1 : c + 1);
            }
        }

        return new Mesh
        {
            vertices = vertices.ToArray(), 
            triangles = triangles.ToArray()
        };
    }
}
```

Then invoke your polydron manager like this:

```
var polyhedronGameObject = PolyhedronManager.CreatePolyhedron("dodecahedron");
```

This script generates vertices and triangles based on the number on sides of the polygon and the dihedral angle of the polyhedron. To do so, it constructs the polyhedron using a Breath-First Search strategy on the faces.

Hope this helps.